# JOIN multiple tables based on one reference table and count records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-join

I have these following tables:

cars:

```
id   manufacturer
--------------------        
1     Nissan
2     Toyota 
3     Honda
4     Volkswagen
```

type:

```
id       type                    car_id
--------------------------------------------
1        maxima                   1
2        civic                    3
3        accord                   3
4        corolla                  2
5        altima                   1
```

color:

```
id      color          car_id
———————————--------------------
1       yellow          1
2       blue            2
3       blue            1
4       black           4
5       red             1
```

desired table:

```
car_id       total_type       total_colors
————————————————---------------------------
1                2                     3               
2                1                     1
3                2                     0
4                0                     1
```

How could I get the resulting table? I would prefer not to use the with clause. Would a `CROSS JOIN` be the optimal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it could be done with 2 LEFT JOINs and COUNT DISTINCT aggregate functions.  Something like this

```
select c.id, count(distinct t.id) total_type, count(distinct co.id) total_colors, 
from cars c
     left join [types] t on c.id=t.car_id
     left join colors co on c.id=co.car_id
group by c.id
order by 1;
```